# Call subclass constructor from parent in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

so I'm learning about java inheritance and I just ran into a situation I don't know how to solve.

What I'm trying to do is to call a subclass constructor from the superclass. I don't know if this makes any sense, but I'll try to explain myself with an example.

```
public class Phone {
    private String brand;
    private int weight;

    public Phone(String brand, int weight) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Phone(String brand, int weight, String tech) {
        // Here it is where I'm stuck
        // Call SmartPhone constructor with all the parameters
    }
}
```

```
public class SmartPhone extends Phone {
    private String tech;

    public SmartPhone(String Brand, int weight, String tech) {
        super(brand, weight);
        this.tech = tech;
    }
}
```

Why would I want to do that?

I would like to be able to not have to deal with SmartPhone in the main.
I'd like to be able to do:

```
Phone nokia = new Phone("Nokia", 295); // <- Regular Phone Instance
Phone iphone = new Phone("iPhone", 368, "4G"); // <- SmartPhone instance
```

Comment: you can do `Phone iphone = new SmartPhone("iPhone", 368, "4G");`

Comment: "What I'm trying to do is to call a subclass constructor from the superclass" - that doesn't really make any sense.  If you want a `SmartPhone`, then just write `new SmartPhone(...)` :)  Or use static helper methods if you really want them to be called the same thing.  Or consider whether polymorphism is actually what you want here (vs. say an `isSmart` boolean field in `Phone`).

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware I could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Phone iphone = new Phone("iPhone", 368, "4G"); // <- SmartPhone instance
```

this makes no sense. If you want a `SmartPhone` instance, you must call

```
Phone iphone = new SmartPhone("iPhone", 368, "4G");
```

You **cannot** call a sub-class constructor from a super-class constructor.

If you want the type of the `Phone` to be determined by the passed parameters, you can use static factory methods:

```
public class PhoneFactory {

    public static Phone newPhone (String brand, int weight) {
        return new Phone(brand, weight);
    }

    public static Phone newPhone (String brand, int weight, String tech) {
        return new SmartPhone(brand, weight, tech);
    }
}

Phone nokia = PhoneFactory.newPhone("Nokia", 295); // <- Regular Phone Instance
Phone iphone = PhoneFactory.newPhone("iPhone", 368, "4G"); // <- SmartPhone instance
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I already imagined that that made no sense, but I jjust wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything!

Answer (score 0):

Calling the constructor of a subclass within the constructor of the base class is not possible. There are various reasons for this but one is that a constructor of a derived class calls, implicitely or explicitly, a constructor of the base class. This would cause an infinite loop.
What you could do, is the following: Create a static method within the base class that decides what instance should be created.

```
public class Phone
{
  ...

  public static Phone createPhone(String brand, int weight, String tech)
  {
    if (tech == null)
      return (new Phone(brand, weight));
    else
      return (new SmartPhone(brand, weight, tech));
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, that's an other option I could use. Thanks for your help, really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a private constructor, and instantiate a `SmartPhone()` object from within the `Phone()` constructor with three parameters.

Comment: Wouldn't that cause infinite recursion?  Can you post some code to show what you mean?